# GWT + Google Visualization API = Firefox add-on

Tags: javascript, jquery, gwt, firefox-addon, google-visualization

I'm planning to take a look at user experience in web application in that way that I will follow user clicks and maybe some other actions during his session. Idea is to show to user his activity using chart.

I already made initial version of chart using Google Visualization API and it looks good for now (even I don't have so much experience in web development, it was very easy to make it using this API and I would recommend it!).

Next step is to make administrative panel that will customize parameters that will be followed (clicks at exact links, clicks at buttons,...), as well as customize  and I planned to make it using GWT because I have seen that Google made good integration of these technologies. As first, what do you think about this integration/combination. Also, I have suggestion to use JQuery as very good and useful library.

When this part of story is finished, I would need to pack it in Firefox add-on (plans are also to make Google Chrome add-on), so users will be able to install it and follow own activity. I was reading that there are some problems in creating Firefox add-on from GWT code. Do anybody has experience with this combination? Is it possible to do and if you have reference for useful materials it will be great!

Also, because I'm beginner at this field, any kind of suggestions, recommendations,... are more than welcome!!!

TnX in advance!

Nemanja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer that:

Add-ons are traditionally developed using XUL. They may include binary components normally written in Java JAR packages (or other programming languages like C++). However, the user interface has to be XUL.

There's no alternative there, so I don't think GWT will help you here unless there is some GWT-XUL converter.

If someone find some other answers it would be good to post it here.